# Compile multiple code files into an assembly with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string code = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
options.GenerateExecutable = false;
options.GenerateInMemory = true;

options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

CompilerResults result;
result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

LastErrors = result.Errors;

if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    throw new Exception("Compiling the code has returned exceptions!\r\nCheck LastErrors for details.");
}
return result.CompiledAssembly;
```

is my code for compiling C# code into an assembly.
But instead, I would like to somehow compile all the files in a directory into that assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you not just use [`CompileAssemblyFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile.aspx) instead? That allows you to specify multiple filenames.

Comment: Woah. I was so scared to touch these methods that I didn't bother looking for this one. Thanks! xD